# Using jQuery to listen for DOM events vs html handles

Tags: javascript, jquery

Originally I wrote standard functions triggered by an `on input` event handler that I placed in the HTML. However, it was recommended to me to rather 'listen' for events using jQuery (to make for more readable code).

Question:
What is the difference in terms of processing between the two? (as in how is the code of each style interacting with the DOM).

Originally I had something like this:

HTML:

```
<input type='range' oninput='doStuff()'../>
```

JS:

```
function doStuff() {
  //Things happen
}
```

Below is the refactored code:

```
var makeMusic = {
    var1: val,
    var2: val,
    var3: val,

    init: function() {      
        makeMusic.watchExperience();
    },

    watchExperience: function() {
        $(document).on('input change', '#input_experience', function() {
            //do stuff
        }
    },

    anotherFunction: function() {
    },

    etc
}

var otherScript = {
    init: function() {
    },

    etc
}


var Main = {
    run: function() {
        makeMusic.init();
        otherScript.init();
    }
}

$(document).ready(Main.run);
```

Comment: i've tried to clarify a bit...

Comment: The main difference would be the scope in which the callback has to be defined. In the HTML only version it has to be the global scope, whereas adding listeners using code can use any scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are talking about custom event dispatchers and redirecting it to a standard event

Based on your example the orginal event given by the browser DOM which is **onchange** if you want to do a proxy for it then you definitely catch that event and trigger your **oninput**

Refer https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events

You can capture all the events at document level or a wilcard ***** selector level and re-trigger **oninput** with a custom code

if you use JQuery it will also help

**The difference is:** you can handle the native hardware events in a more sophisticated manner. This allows you create your own framework which give more proper event names.

Comment: I think what this means is that when you call a handler from the element directly you can create an event 'proxy' (i.e. a different event for that event), which you wouldn't (easily) be able to do if observing indirectly with JQuery. The JQuery approach allows for separating concerns, which is good and allows for more complicated development. is this summary correct?

Comment: Yes, you are actually thinking about naming the event with a proper name, like jQuery Mobile onpagecreate, onpagechange like that